# Old 70's Sci-Fi B-movie: Earth is being invaded by telepathic aliens

Tags: story-identification, b-movies

I believe the movie was made in the 70's. (at least it was during that time I saw it). It was in color.  The only part I can remember is that Earth was being invaded (of course) by telepathic (or psionic) aliens that are humanoid. I seem to remember a scene during the invasion when the (main ??) character is attacked psychically by an invader and had to break off contact because their mind was too powerful. I also seem to remember that the alien involved in the duel makes some kind of statement that it had been impressed with the human's intelligence and power.  I know it's not much to go on but it was 35+ years ago.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/152918/edit) any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Do you recall what the aliens looked like? Was the movie in colour or in black and white? As the question currently stands, there's not much to go on. Telepathic aliens are a common trope, as is the notion of a human befriending or otherwise being special to them. An example would be Professor Gordon Zellaby in _Village of the Damned_, played by George Sanders.

Comment: I wish I could come up with more. Wracked my brain all last night and this was pretty much all I could remember.